# Why doesn't `T` coerce to `Option<T>`?

Tags: rust

This function doesn't compile:

```rust
fn greet() -> Option<String> {
    String::from("Hello")
}
```

The compiler justifiably complains that I'm returning a `String`, not an `Option<String>`:

```text
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:6:12
  |
5 | fn greet() -> Option<String> {
  |               -------------- expected `Option<String>` because of return type
6 |     String::from("Hello")
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Option<String>`, found `String`
  |
  = note: expected enum `Option<String>`
           found struct `String`
help: try wrapping the expression in `Some`
  |
6 |     Some(String::from("Hello"))
  |     +++++                     +

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

It seems like there's an obvious way to coerce it, though – the compiler even suggests it – wrap it in `Some()`. Why did the Rust language designers decide to require an explicit conversion for this specific case? I understand that Rust generally opts for making things explicit, but it offers *some* type coercion, so I'm wondering what made this case different.

Comment: Are you asking "What are Rust's rules for implicit coercion?" or are you asking "Why did the Rust language designers decide to require an explicit conversion for this specific case?" or are you asking "Did the language desingers make the right decision when they decided to require an explicit conversion for this case?" The former two questions are not opinion-based, while the last one is.

Comment: The second one, edited, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps to avoid pitfalls like <https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2018/12/09/deducing-your-intentions/>.

Comment: Rust offers very few "visible" type conversions, mainly for primitive types (ie. a `[T; N]` can be converted into `[T]`) and with variance and lifetimes (ie. a `&'static str` can be converted to `&'a str` for any `'a`).

Answer (score 0):

Well, coercions are easy with the `.into()` method. [The code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=fn+greet%28%29+-%3E+Option%3CString%3E+%7B%0A++++String%3A%3Afrom%28%22Hello%22%29.into%28%29%0A%7D%0A) works due to two traits, which are specifically designed for conversions:

- [From](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#impl-From%3CT%3E-for-Option%3CT%3E) — `Option<T>` can be derived from any value of type `T` by applying `Some(..)`
- [Into](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.Into.html) — `value.into()` calls `Option::from(value)`, which is `Some(value)`

On the other hand, the [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html) type is an enumeration. What makes it so different from the `Result` type (or any other enum)? Should it work in closures too? Will newcomers be ok with behavior inconsistency? Should we complicate the language, the type system, the type checker, and the compiler's code? And so on.

Comment: I would argue "yes we should complicate it that way."  This is analogous to how in C++ if you have a return type, and it has a converting constructor for what you're trying to return (and it's not `explicit`) it'll "just work."  If the return type implements `From<T>` and you return it, `.into()` just happens, because return types are explicit.  You can't ask the compiler to do "magic" when chaining things, but with return types?  That's in-bounds IMO.